# mysql , perl script freezing when retrieving data

Tags: mysql, perl

Hi I have this code. my perl scripts hangs somewhere in the @row section. I printed the next query statement and it works in SQL.

Why is it hanging?

```
foreach $device (...)

        $sth2 = $dbh->prepare(qq|SELECT DISTINCT S,`W(m)`,`L(m)`,V FROM `$SQL_TABLE_NAME` WHERE DEVICE='$device'| );
        $sth2->execute(  );
        my %TEMP = ();
        while ( my @row = $sth2->fetchrow_array(  )) 
        {
            $TEMP{S}{$row[0]} = 1;
            $TEMP{W}{$row[1]}       = 1;
            $TEMP{L}{$row[2]}       = 1;
            $TEMP{V}{$row[3]}     = 1;

        }
```

Comment: I found out that by changing the order of S and V variable extraction changes fixes my script ... what gives ...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a syntax error in your query (`VFROM` rather than `V FROM`).

If the query fails, there's no result set to fetch a row from. You might want to build some error handling into your code.

Comment: sorry, it was a paste mistake, just to make my variables generic ... still having issues

Comment: Principle stands, are you checking you got a result from that query before trying to read the result set?

Comment: It's freezing at the execute command. It's not entering into the while loop yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $select_line = qq|SELECT DISTINCT S,`W(m)`,`L(m)`,V 
 FROM `$SQL_TABLE_NAME` 
 WHERE DEVICE='$device'|;
```

Have you tried printing the $select_line and then running it directly in mysql?

```
my $sth2 = $dbh->prepare( $select_line ) 
 or die $DBI::errstr.' at my query: $select_line\n';
```

1. Add in `or die $DBI::errstr.' at my query: $select_line'` to verify if your syntax is correct.
2. Add in   `die $sth2->errstr if $sth2->err;` after your while:

   > while (fetch) {
   >
   > //stuff in here with rows
   >
   > } die $sth2->errstr if $sth2->err;
3. Review CPAN DBI docs @ http://metacpan.org/pod/DBI

Answer (score 0):

By the way it's better to use placeholders:

```
$sth2 = $dbh->prepare(qq|SELECT DISTINCT S,`W(m)`,`L(m)`,V FROM `$SQL_TABLE_NAME` WHERE DEVICE= ?| );
$sth2->execute($device);
```